# Why are two identical lines in this context here non-parallel?

Tags: linear-algebra

I came across this question on Linear Algebra: concepts and techniques on euclidean spaces (second edition)

[image]

This is the answer given for the question:
[image]

I do not understand why did they mention x + y - z =1 twice and state that they are two non-parallel line? With my understanding, shouldn't two identical line be parallel to each other?

Comment: Maybe it is a misprint for "$x+y-z=1$ and $x-2y+z=0$ are two non-parallel planes..."

Comment: Looks like a typo and that they mean to refer to the two components of B. There evidently isn't a lot of care put into the answer key, as $x+y-z=1$ doesn't describe a line in the first place, it describes a plane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a copy-paste misprint. It should read:

> Since $x+y-z=1$ and $x-2y+z=0$ are two non-parallel planes, $\ldots$

Comment: It should read two non-parallel *planes* - neither of those equations represent a line.

Comment: Thank you @NuclearHoagie. Corrected.